# position an svg image under a span

Tags: css, svg, position

I would like to position an svg image under a span of text.  I don't want to include some space in the svg because I will use this with various sizes of text.

Tried a bunch of css styles, but can't seem to get it.

CSS:

```
  .a_underline{
            background: url('~/images/highlight.svg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            }
```

HTML:

```
I would like to <span class="a_underline">underline</span> some text
```

I end up with this!

[image: results]

Would like the orange svg to be below "underline"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to play with `background position` to set at the bottom. check snippet.

```css
.a_underline {
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/200x5/000/fff') bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
I would like to <span class="a_underline">underline l ldlvjnlvnnlkk bkbk</span> some text
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was sure it was something simple.  Perfect.  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I am glad that helped upvote will be really helpful.